# Add a Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a Rails application that allows users to create posts (like a blog) and I wondered how can I add the date it was created. How can add that?

Comment: Your Model Post has (generated by default, as every models in Rails) 2 columns "created_at" and "updated_at". Maybe you can use that?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: not by default, only when using the `timestamps` method in the `create_table` migration method. If you are talking about the generator, yes, that will always have it.

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect although how do I add it in `erb`?

Comment: `<%= post.created_at %>` (if you want a nicer format, use strftime: `<%= post.created_at.strftime('%d %m %Y') %>`

Comment: Thank you! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails offers the `timestamps` method when writing a `create_table` migration, which automatically creates a `created_at` and an `updated_at` timestamp, and fill them accordingly when the entry is created/updated.

Comment: How do I add that in `erb`?

Comment: @user1919937 by asking that question I advise stop whatever you are doing. Head over to [`Ruby on Rails guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) and read something about Ruby on Rails framework. After that you can get real 'hands-on' at [`Railscasts`](http://railscasts.com)

Answer (score 0):

Every rails model already has by deafault `created_at` column which is always updated when record is saved for first time.

```
post = Post.first
puts post.created_at
```